# Tansfer data from one table to partitioned table took more time

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-administration

Scenario:   We have a Staging table (consider it as Table A) which is refreshed Every  month. Every    month table A is truncated and inserted 
with 6 million records approx. Once the mandatory update done on Table A we have to move the records to main table (Table B). 
Table B is Partitioned by month wise, which contains the complete history of records from the year 2010.
Table B has 1 clus. index(month column) and 3 non clustered index. Currently table B has 180,562,235 records.
While transfer i didn’t disable the index, because it was taking more for enabling the index again.

Question:       Data transfer from table A to table B took 2.30 hours approx. I need to reduce transfer time.

Any Suggestion to reduce the time will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use partition switch. Align your indexes with the partition, then switch in the staging using [ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH PARTITION  ...](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273(v=sql.105).aspx). It's basically instantaneous. Read [Transferring Data Efficiently by Using Partition Switching](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160(v=sql.105).aspx) for all the details.

Comment: I read the topics shared. I tried with some examples. Switching partition emptying the source table and move into the target.In my scenario i need the source table records as it loaded.we are maintain the source table(Staging) month wise.

Comment: Successfully implemented the partition switching in my project. It took 4 seconds to transfer from staging to main table. Thanks a lot.